# Migrating pagelayouts using ant

Tags: ant

How do i migrate pagelayout using ant.

These are the steps i followed

1. Called sf:retrieve in Ant and specified the custom object name in package.xml
2. Retrieved object definition does not have page layouts in it
3. after the retrieve when i try to deploy,sf:deploy,can see no page layouts are getting deployed.

How do i do this?

I want to deploy pagelayouts for standard objects(Account,Contacts) and custom objects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your package.xml needs to include the "Layout" type. It is usually best to explicitly name the layouts where the syntax is objectname-layoutname e.g.:

```
<types>
    <members>Account-Claims Account Layout</members>
    <members>Contact-Claims Contact Layout</members>
    <members>MyCustomObject__c-MyCustomObject Layout</members>
    <name>Layout</name>
</types>
```

**PS** package.xml is documented in detail in the [Metadata API Developer’s
Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/api_meta.pdf).

Comment: do i need to explicitly list out names...or is there a way to include all pagelayouts of an object in one go

Comment: This type does support the `<members>*</members>` wildcard but as orgs normally contain a lot of objects and so layouts that you are not interested in that wouldn't be too helpful. AFAIK you cannot wildcard part of a name; the documentation says "a wildcard character (*) in place of the model name". So I think you will be better off explicitly naming them.